# AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'mousePressEvent'

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having trouble with two tkinter classes that I want to interact. I think it comes from my lack of understanding of the `Tk.Toplevel`. Instead of creating an entirely new full-screen window for screen-grabbing, my code gives an error:

```
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'mousePressEvent'
```

Can someone help me understand the hierarchy of parent-child relationships in my code? I'm not asking anyone to rewrite my code, I just want to understand what I already have, so I can figure out what's wrong. I haven't found many examples in SO of multiple classes that interact with multiple windows - so it's hard to grasp the inter-workings of inheritance.

*This is the structure I think I have:*

- root

  - object: AquireImage

    - method: show_dialogs()
    - object: ScreenSnip

      - method: get_snip()
      - method: mousePressEvent()
      - method: mouseMoveEvent()
      - method: mouseReleaseEvent()

*Is this accurate?*

**CODE**

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageGrab, ImageTk, Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tkinter import filedialog


class ScreenSnip(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

    def get_snip(self):
        self.configure(cursor='cross')
        self.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        self.attributes('-alpha', 0.4)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='dark gray')
        self.canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        self.begin_x = 0
        self.begin_y = 0
        self.end_x = 0
        self.end_y = 0
        self.click_drag = False

        self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0, outline='#0052d6', width=2, fill='white', tags='snip_rect')
        self.canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.mousePressEvent)
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.mouseMoveEvent)
        self.canvas.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.mouseReleaseEvent)

        print('Capture the screen...')

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.begin_x = event.x
        self.begin_y = event.y
        print(self.begin_x,self.begin_y)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.click_drag = True
        self.end_x = event.x
        self.cur_y = event.y
        width = self.end_x - self.begin_x
        height = abs(width * 2/3)
        if self.cur_y < self.begin_y:
            height *= -1
        self.end_y = self.begin_y + height
        self.canvas.coords('snip_rect', self.begin_x, self.begin_y, self.end_x, self.end_y)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.destroy()
        self.master.update_idletasks()
        self.master.after(100)  # give time for screen to be refreshed so as not to see the blue box on the screenshot
        if not self.click_drag: # if the user just clicks, instead of clicking and dragging
            self.begin_x -= 300
            self.begin_y += 200
            self.end_x = self.begin_x + 600
            self.end_y = self.begin_y - 400
        x1 = min(self.begin_x, self.end_x)
        y1 = min(self.begin_y, self.end_y)
        x2 = max(self.begin_x, self.end_x)
        y2 = max(self.begin_y, self.end_y)

        img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
        self.img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        cv2.imshow('Captured Image', self.img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
font1 = ("arial", 18, "bold")

class AcquireImage:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.fontA = ("arial", 20, "bold")

        self.frame = tk.Frame(master, bg="#1B2631")
        self.frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Select Image File", padx=10, pady=10, bg="#d9a193",
                              font = self.fontA, command =lambda: self.show_dialogs(1))
        self.button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")#, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.button2 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Get Screen Snip", padx=10, pady=10, bg="#d9a193",
                              font = self.fontA, command=lambda: self.show_dialogs(2))
        self.button2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")#, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.image_selected = None

    def show_dialogs(self, method):

        if method == 1:
            ret = filedialog.askopenfilename() #filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/home/user/images/')
            if ret:
                self.image_selected = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = ret)
                self.master.destroy()

        elif method == 2:
            newWin = ScreenSnip.get_snip(self.master)
            ret = newWin.img
            if ret:
                self.image_selected = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = ret)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    AcquireImage(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: *Instances* of `ScreenSnip` would indeed have a `mousePressEvent` attribute.  But you never create any such instance; instead, you attempt to call `get_snip()` on the class itself, which ends up providing a completely inappropriate value for its `self` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for noting that @jasonharper. I changed my code to `newWin = ScreenSnip(self.master); newWin.get_snip()` and it seems to be working. I think I needed to create the object `newWin` with parent `self.master` first, then I can call the method `get_snip` instead of trying to do both in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is derived from @jasonharper's comment:

> Instances of `ScreenSnip` would indeed have a `mousePressEvent`
> attribute. But you never create any such instance; instead, you
> attempt to call `get_snip()` on the class itself, which ends up
> providing a completely inappropriate value for its `self` parameter.

The mistake I made was here:

```
newWin = ScreenSnip.get_snip(self.master)
```

I tried to create a new object `newWin` without putting the parent in the correct place, and while calling the method `get_snip` at the same time. This is what solved the issue:

```
newWin = ScreenSnip(self.master)
newWin.get_snip()
```

First create the object `ScreenSnip` from the class, with the parent
then call the method `get_snip'

Comment: If this works, you could do it in one line with `ScreenSnip(self.master).get_snip()`